# Apache POI - Can't apply format to Cell

Tags: java, apache-poi

I'm trying to apply this cell format in ApachePOI:

```
XSSFCellStyle cellStyle  = myWorkBook.createCellStyle();        
    XSSFDataFormat format = myWorkBook.createDataFormat();
    cellStyle.setDataFormat(format.getFormat("h:mm:ss,000"));
```

But when I open Excel, gives this error:
"Style from /xl/styles.xml part (styles) Undreadable Content"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved using this format: ""[hh]:mm:ss.000""

Comment: don't forget to mark your answer as the correct one